# MDX Get MAX MEMBER_KEY from Dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimensions

I have a very simple SSAS dimension which looks like this:

Dimension Name: **DimKeyword**

1 Attribute: **Keyword** with KeywordID as the **KeyColumn** and Keyword (name) as the **NameColumn**

Using MDX, I want to get one row with the **Max** MEMBER_KEY for the DimKeyword dimension (without listing all the Keywords), so far I have:

```
WITH MEMBER KeywordID as
[Dim Keyword].[Keyword].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY
SELECT {KeywordID} on COLUMNS
FROM [Some Cube]
```

Although this seems to only return 0 (which I assume is for the member ). Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the max function:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Max key] AS
    Max([Dim Keyword].[Keyword].Members, [Dim Keyword].[Keyword].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY)
SELECT {[Measures].[Max key]} on COLUMNS
FROM [Some Cube]
```

And if you want to have the Keyword member that has the highest `MEMBER_KEY`, you can use:

```
TopCount([Dim Keyword].[Keyword].Members, 1, [Dim Keyword].[Keyword].currentmember.MEMBER_KEY).Item(0).Item(0)
```